# Timing of information sending via socket (TCP, C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I work on a C++ program that uses TCP communication between client and server. At some point in the program, there is a loop in which the server sends to the client a serialized object, object1, of size x, and after that a serialized object, object2, of size y. The client has a loop with two sequential recv() calls to receive these objects.

the problem is that sometimes  the first recv() in the client receive object of size (x+y), i.e. the server sent the two objects before the client even started waiting for object1. how can this be prevented?

Comment: You can't prevent it - TCP is a streaming protocol, not a packet protocol. You need to add your own protocol with object boundaries on top of it.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it? That just saves you a second call to `recv`, which is a huge win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Described problem is effect of streaming nature of TCP. This means that TCP protocol doesn't care about message borders. So you need add them.

One possible solution is to add header before any object sent via the connection. For example:

```
x <object1> y <object2>
```

Where x and y are 32-bit numbers. When you read data from connection you at first step read sizeof object and then object itself.

This solution is much better than message acknowledge approach because sender doesn't have to wait before send second object.

One more note you may wish to know: in networking protocol you need care about byte order of the integers. You may see details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent that if you just send object2, if the client successfully received object1.

The client answers your server if he got 1 object successfully, then your server can send the next object. You could do that by creating some telegrams that your client and server knows.